# What properties of a magic item can be identified with skill checks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, skills

Let's say a Level 1 Cleric finds a very powerful ring (e.g. [Ring of Three Wishes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-three-wishes)). Since the cleric has no idea what this ring is for, what kinds of skill checks etc. can he use at which DC to identify the ring fully?

What information would you as a GM reveal to the cleric player if he makes a skill check of 5, 10, 15, 20, 25?

I could not find useful guidelines for this kind of "detect magic" or "spellcraft checks".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Skills can't be used for this directly. Instead, the [*detect magic*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/detect-magic) and [*identify*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/identify) spells are used, which grant spellcraft checks as part of their spell effects.

> **[Spellcraft](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/spellcraft)**
>   This skill is also used to identify the properties of magic items in your possession through the use of spells such as *detect magic* and *identify*.

*Detect magic* grants you the opportunity to make spellcraft checks after studying an item for three rounds, while *identify* works identically except it gives you a +10 to those checks. Clerics don't normally get *identify*, so they're stuck with the bonus-less *detect magic*.

According to the game, a successful check reveals all the properties of an item. GMs might adjust this to fit the way magic works in their campaign, of course.

Comment: So there is just the possibility of either you know everything or nothing at all about the functionality of the object?

Comment: @mawimawi As written, yeah. If that seems unsatisfying, a house rule inserted there to make the process more interesting/complicated/non-binary wouldn't upset anything else (unless it upsets your players, in which case the usual "what do we consider fun?" conversation is incoming).

Comment: Keep the last sentence in mind always.  Why did my bag of holding try to eat me the first time I used it?  I apparently was expected to make a knowledge planes check to detect that.

Comment: @David Wilkins I really want to hear that story now...

Comment: @GreySage Bag of Devouring looks like a Bag of Holding.